# I get this error when I try to convert a list from a Snowpark df to a Pandas df: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, list, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here's the loop I use to create (via appending) to my list:

```
results=[]
for col in df_col:
    results.append(col['COLUMN_NAME'])    
print(results)
```

When I try to run the following code:

```
results = results.to_pandas()
```

I get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_pandas'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `results` is a `list`.

List has no attribute `'to_pandas'`.

If you want to convert your snowpark dataframe to pandas then you can:

```
pandas_df = snowpark_df.to_pandas()
```